# Limit of sequences.

Tags: limits

Could someone tell me how one could work out the limit of the following:
1) Ax= (1.001)^x) / (x^1000) as x->∞

2.) Bx=( 1^100 +2^100+......n^100) ^1/n as n->∞ .

I know the final answers but I can't really show how do you get there step by step. Any help?

Comment: Look at the difference of what you think the answer is and the value foe some number n, as the n increases does the difference goes to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$1\le\left(1^{100}+2^{100}+\ldots +n^{100}\right)^{1/n}\le(n^{101})^{1/n}=\left(\sqrt[n]n\right)^{101}\ldots\text{and squeeze...}$$

For the first one, apply l'Hospital 1000 times:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1.001^x}{x^{1000}}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1.001^x\log 1000}{1000x^{999}}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1.001^x\log^21000}{1000\cdot999x^{998}}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\ldots$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This might sound stupid but according to what (n^101)^1/n is greater or equal to the sum up to 100?
And as for the second. I don't know about l'Hospital >.< Started analysis just a month ago.

Comment: @MrSmith : $$1^{100}\le n^{100}\;,\;2^{100}\le n^{100}\;,\;...\implies\ldots$$

Comment: Many many thanks